# Word 2010 Checkbox - Hiding line items that are unchecked to print only checked items

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a list of items that each have a checkbox control at the beginning of the line. I would like to create a subroutine that, after the user applies checkmarks on each item the want/need, will scan the document for all UNCHECKED items and apply a style that hides that item. The finished result will then be printed (without the unchecked items being visible of course.)

I have searched everywhere to find out how to determine the checkbox object name(s) individually in order to navigate to each one and apply the style based on its on/off status. OR, I've tried to find out how to collectively hide all unchecked items in a checkbox collection.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!